# Make container overflow its parent without making the parent bigger in IE 6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, overflow, visible

I used the three column layout in A List Apart's ["In Search of The Holy Grail"](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/) article for a store I'm working on that uses Magento. Inside the middle column, at the top, there's a container that I would like to overflow so it extends outside the middle column and goes over the top of the right column. Like below.

```
_______________________________
|     |                       |
|     |  Middle/Top           |
|Left |_______________________|
|     |                 |     |
|     |  Middle/Main    |Right|
|_____|_________________|_____|
```

The way I've got it works fine in all modern browsers, but in IE 6 the overflowing Middle/Top section causes the width of the Middle/Main section to expand an contain it.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: off the top of my head I would think using z-index would allow this. Can you post your markup / css?

Comment: If you can't find a cross browser solution, consider using conditional comments to selectively include a IE only CSS file.

Comment: @KP Here's what I'm working with http://dev.baseballtips.com/magento132/bats/bare-butt-bat.html

Comment: thats not really the structure im seeing in your link. I mean visually it is but markup-wise its not... can you ammend the link in your comment to your actual question and update the arbitrary names with the id's/classes used in that link?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see in IE6 is that the `#sub-content` and `#sidebar` are in the wrong place, horizontally. Try making a minimal test case and compare your structure and styling to the Holy Grail structure and styling. One difference is you've swapped the left and right columns (`#sidebar` should come before `#sub-content`). Fix that to start.

Comment: Thanks outis, I didn't even realize I did that. I'll fix that and see what problems are still occuring.